# Setting the PDF Content Creator with xattr

Tags: shell, applescript, xattr

I am try to take a Finder selection and assign a specific content creator value to pdf files using applescript and xattr. While the script compiles fine, it doesn't actually modify the metadata item. If I run `mdls -n kMDItemCreator test.pdf` I still get the old value of the kMDItemCreator. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
-- Get the finder selection to pass to the repeat below
tell application "Finder"
    set finderSelectionList to selection as alias list
end tell

-- Change the content creator of the selected files

repeat with theFile in finderSelectionList
    tell application "Finder"
        set a to quoted form of POSIX path of theFile
        do shell script "xattr -w com.apple.metadata:kMDItemCreator 'some content creator'" & a
    end tell
 end repeat
```

Comment: are you missing a space before adding & a? check also if you need admin privileges or if the file is protected.

Comment: On further investigation, these seems to be related to differences between  how xattr and mdls read and write to the kMDItemCreator field. I will update if I learn more.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. did you find the solution ??? @GForce

Comment: @Rhea I used the solution here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7999590